# yacc associativity of nonterminal symbols?

Tags: yacc

Say I have a grammar like this:

```
expr : expr '+' expr   { $$ = operation('+', $1, $3); }
     | expr '-' expr   { $$ = operation('-', $1, $3); }
     | expr '*' expr   { $$ = operation('*', $1, $3); }
     | expr '/' expr   { $$ = operation('/', $1, $3); }
     | num
     ;
```

Where each of those operators has a precedence attached and is marked as left associative.

Then I want to refactor my grammar such that:

```
op   : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' ;

expr : expr op expr { $$ = operation($2, $1, $3); }
     | num
     ;
```

How does yacc (if even at all) determine the associativity and precedence of `op` in this case?  Will it trace its way through all the possible precedences/associativities of `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` when evaluating `op`, or does defining an associativity for nonterminal symbols make no sense?

AFAIK, with precedence order for nonterminals, it uses the precedence of the rightmost terminal symbol, but I can't find any documentation on the associativity rules themselves for nonterminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" way to do this (as far as I'm aware) is to define a different expr type for each operator, that way you get very explicit control over what's happening.

Python's grammar is a good example of this: http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html.

Comment: Thanks, I know this isn't really a good way to structure the grammar. I've got my own LALR(1) parser (in ruby) and the operator precedence/associativity doesn't work when there's a nonterminal rule between the operator and the operands, so I was mostly curious if/how yacc handles this. I personally try to avoid it, but one of my users tripped up on it, and neither us noticed the cause; which led me to wonder if it's easily fixable.